# simple google chrome extension to detect clicks on a web page- no alert is being displayed (error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

This is the js code I have put in a content script named 'detectclicks.js' to detect clicks on any portion of a web page open in the browser- it uses Jquery--- However no alert is being displayed...

```
$('body').on('click', '*', function(event) {
     window.alert(' ID of element- testing'); 
    window.alert(' ID of element=' + $(this).attr('id'));  // Get ID attribute
    window.alert(' ID of Parent element=' + $(this).parent()..attr('id'));
});
```

And this is my manifest.json--

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery1.7.2.js", "detectclicks.js"]
      }
   ],
   "description": "The first extension that I made.",
   "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
    } 
}
```

No alert is being displayed when I load this extension into Google Chrome and visit a web page..click on any part of the page...What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Double dots in here `parent()..attr('id')` is typo, isn't it?

Comment: @VisioN - i missed that :( its not a typo... that s the code i put in the extension :( ... i corrected it and now its working fine :) Thanks :) you can put that as the answer and i will mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, check it should not be double dots in this line:

```
window.alert('ID of Parent element=' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
```

Be attentive! ;)